# move семантика при релокации и слиянии вектора

Tags: c++, c++17

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "v1 creation" << std::endl;

    std::vector<Movable> v1{
        std::string{"1"},
        std::string{"2"},
        std::string{"3"},
        std::string{"4"},
        std::string{"5"} };

    std::cout << "v1 creation end" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "v2 creation" << std::endl;

    std::vector<Movable> v2{
        std::string{"6"},
        std::string{"7"},
        std::string{"8"},
        std::string{"9"},
        std::string{"10"} };

    std::cout << "v2 creation end" << std::endl;

    v1.reserve(v1.size() + v2.size());

    std::cout << "move" << std::endl;

    v1.insert(v1.end(), std::make_move_iterator(v2.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(v2.end()));

    std::cout << "v1: " << v1.size() << std::endl;

    for (const auto& it : v1)
    {
        it.print();
    }

    std::cout << "v2: " << v2.size() << std::endl;

    for (const auto& it : v2)
    {
        it.print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
...
v2 creation end
Ctor <const Movable&>
Ctor <const Movable&>
Ctor <const Movable&>
Ctor <const Movable&>
Ctor <const Movable&>
move
Ctor <Movable&&>
Ctor <Movable&&>
Ctor <Movable&&>
Ctor <Movable&&>
Ctor <Movable&&>
v1: 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
v2: 5
```

Если закоментировать строку  `v1.reserve(v1.size() + v2.size());`, то вывод меняется на

```
v2 creation end
move
Ctor <Movable&&>
Ctor <Movable&&>
Ctor <Movable&&>
Ctor <Movable&&>
Ctor <Movable&&>
Ctor <Movable&&>
Ctor <Movable&&>
Ctor <Movable&&>
Ctor <Movable&&>
Ctor <Movable&&>
...
```

Вопрос1: почему при релокации вектора, вызываемой `reserve` вызывается конструктор копирования, а не мув-конструктор и можно ли от вектора добиться вызова мув-конструкторов при релокации?

Вопрос2: почему при вставке без `reserve` мы уже видим, что импользуется мув-семантика?

Comment: (1) Вектор брезгует перемещающим конструктором при изменении размера, если тот не `noexcept` и есть копирующий конструктор. Вроде бы для лучшей exception-safety.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, тэкс, добавил noexcept, при релокации заработал мув-конструктор, а где можно про это почитать? интересует вот что: такое поведение реализовано на всех платформах или отдано на откуп разработчикам стандартной библиотеки и от платформе к платформе может различаться?

Comment: Не получается нормальное объяснение найти, но да, это должно работать везде одинаково.